# Scala: How to transform an HList of ValidatedNel into a ValidatedNel of HList

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-cats

I've been using `cats.data.Validated` successfully to solve the problem below, but have come into a problem using my existing solution for a case class with more than 22 members (because the constructor cannot be made into a `Function`).

Here is my goal: generate a bunch of `ValidatedNel[E, T]`, sequence them into a `ValidatedNel[E, (T1, T2, ...)]`, then `mapN(DAOClass)` (where `DAOClass` is a `case class` with the specified arguments). This works for fewer than 22 arguments, but fails with more because of two problems:

1. `(T1, T2, ...)` cannot have more than 22 components
2. `DAOClass.apply` cannot be transformed into a `Function`

So I am looking into using `shapeless.HList` to handle part 1 and having problems. I should be able to use [`Generic[DAOClass]`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) to satisfactorily handle part 2 when I get to it, or if that doesn't work, use  [extensible records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records) with a bit more boilerplate.

Here is some small example code (not with 22 components):

```
package example

import cats.syntax.validated._
import cats.data.ValidatedNel
import cats.sequence._
import shapeless._

case class DAOClass(a: Int, b: Int)

object DAOClass {

  def generate: ValidatedNel[String, DAOClass] = {

    val hlist: ValidatedNel[String, Int] :: ValidatedNel[String, Int] :: HNil =
      1.validNel :: 2.validNel :: HNil

    val hlistSequence: ValidatedNel[String, Int :: Int :: HNil] = hlist.sequence

    hlistSequence.map(Generic[DAOClass].from)

  }

}
```

This uses the `kittens` library to sequence the `HList`.

Unfortunately, this gives me a compile error:

```
[error] ...src/main/scala/example/DAOClass.scala:17:73: cannot construct sequencer, make sure that every item of your hlist shapeless.:: [cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Int],shapeless.::[cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Int],shapeless.HNil]] is an Apply
[error]     val hlistSequence: ValidatedNel[String, ::[Int, ::[Int, HNil]]] = hlist.sequence
[error]                                                                             ^
```

I have extracted this into a test project; here's my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.6",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "shapeless-validation",
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
    ),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.chuusai"   %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0",
      "org.typelevel" %% "kittens"   % "1.1.0"
    )
  )
```

What am I missing? Do I need to import more implicits somewhere? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

to `build.sbt`. For normal work with `cats` this is usually mandatory.

Now

```
hlistSequence.map(Generic[DAOClass].from)
```

produces a `ValidatedNel[String, DAOClass]`:

```
println(DAOClass.generate) // Valid(DAOClass(1,2))
```

Comment: Perfect! With `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` in my [build.sbt](https://github.com/meustrus/shapeless-validation/blob/master/build.sbt), [this 26-member DAO](https://github.com/meustrus/shapeless-validation/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/DAOClass26.scala) can be generated from an `HList` of `ValidatedNel`s!